# Android device not detected on fresh Odin install

Tags: usb, filesystem, android

I just set up my new desktop machine yesterday and want to use Elementary as my OS. Had no trouble with the installer and was able to write the OS to my primary SSD and am writing this message from within Elementary OS 6 Odin.

I've had the usual handful of teething issues with a new install but one thing I can't find a solution to which I'm sure is a software problem is that I can't get my machine to detect my Galaxy S9 over USB.

I know the cable supports data transfer as I use it often on my laptop which runs Ubuntu 20.04 Focal Fossa. I tried some websearching around, installing `android-tools-adb` etc., but that didn't help.

Interestingly, it's not even detected by adb or lsusb:

```
 adb devices
List of devices attached
```

```
$ lsusb
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 04ca:0061 Lite-On Technology Corp. USB Optical Mouse
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 04ca:0027 Lite-On Technology Corp. USB Multimedia Keyboard
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 8087:0029 Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 05e3:0610 Genesys Logic, Inc. 4-port hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0b05:1939 ASUSTek Computer, Inc. AURA LED Controller
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

I also know that the USB ports I'm connecting to work as I used them to transfer files from a flash drive earlier.

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you see any message in `/var/log/syslog` after plugging the phone into the USB port? If the device is being blocked by the phone or some other process, there will be a message there explaining *why* it cannot connect (or appear in `lsusb`) 

Comment: Hi, thanks for the quick reply! For unrelated reasons I ended up having to do a full reinstall and it seems to work now, but only after I have my device plugged in for about a full minute. The relevant section of the log is here:
https://pastelink.net/3jfhq